# How can I access a variable-referenced array element in Meteor spacebars?

Tags: javascript, templates, meteor, spacebars

In a [spacebars](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/spacebars) template, I have a javascript array `x` and an index into it `i`, eg.

```
Template.test.helpers({
    'foo': function() {
        return {
            x: ['aa','bb','cc'],
            i: 1
        }
    }
});
```

I can access fixed elements of `x` in the template with `{{ x.[1] }}`:

```
{{template name="test"}}
    {{#with foo}}
        {{x.[1]}}
    {{/with}}
{{/template}}
```

But `{{ x.[i] }}` doesn't work.

How can I access `x[i]`?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to define a custom helper:

```
Template.test.helpers({
    'getElement': function(a, i) {
        return a[i];
    }
});
```

And then in the template, use:

```
{{ getElement x i }}
```

Answer (score 0):

With such a basic example, I think your helper solution is the most straightforward; however, the goal should always be to move the logic away from the view layer (helpers & html), which is why if spacebars seems limiting, it's just a gentle reminder to refactor.

For more complex problems, a cleaner approach might be to resolve x[i] before you need to use it in your template, or turn x into an object. For example, save x[i] to a data context, or a module object & access it directly. Referencing things by their array index makes life suck when you revisit the code in a month...